# Android ImageButton cut off from screen

Tags: android, android-image

How can I place an image button at the bottom of my screen so that a part of it, let's say half, or 20dp, is not on the screen.

If it would be a circle, we would see half a circle at the bottom of the screen.

EDIT:
layout added

```
<RelativeLayout <!-- upper level layout-->
     ...>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/myButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/my_image_button" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="SOME TEXT\nON DRAWABLE"
            android:textColor="@color/bg_start"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried using margin/padding with alignment on the bottom?

Comment: Post your layout file, please.

Comment: @MocialovBoris this doesn't seem to work

Comment: @dumazy what exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have `RelativeLayout` and `ImageButton` inside it:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

add `layout_alignParentBottom` property to your `RelativeLayout`:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

and `layout_marginTop` to the `ImageButton`

```
android:layout_marginTop="some dp"
```

**EDIT-after published layout**

add `android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"` - not the best solution, but a solution. Try with device (if it actually works). Designer shows half of the image & text moved out of the layout borders

```
<RelativeLayout <!-- upper level layout-->
     ...>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/myButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/my_image_button" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="SOME TEXT\nON DRAWABLE"
            android:textColor="@color/bg_start"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

OR add `layout_marginTop="some dp"` to your ImageView and TextView

```
<RelativeLayout <!-- upper level layout-->
     ...>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/myButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/my_image_button" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="SOME TEXT\nON DRAWABLE"
            android:textColor="@color/bg_start"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it does not seem to work, it's actually quite complicated because I have to display some text on this imagebutton as well. I'm using a framelayout out with an imagebutton and textview within for this

Comment: @dumazy post your layout